# How to get file(-path) of resource after installation of program

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read data from an xml-file after installing it on a computer. I can't figure out how to determine the file path of my xml resource file. I am using ClickOnce to create the setup file.
To be clear, I do succeed in reading the file while running in debug mode (..\bin\Debug\xmlFile.xml).
Can you advise me on how to correctly get the resource's file path?

I have tried adding the following:
- adding the file to the application files
- setting "Build Action" to "Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always"

These are the code snippets with which I'm currently trying to get the filepath:

1 `Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\xmlFile.xml"`

2 `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\xmlFile.xml`

3 `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\xmlFile.xml"`

4 `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\xmlFile.xml"`

5 `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\xmlFile.xml"`

6 `Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\xmlFile.xml"`

7 `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\xmlFile.xml"`

The problem with all above attempts is that they return the path

> C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\8B40KE8T.5W0\VMZ0NKW3.PQR\bsb...tion_16b074f657bf9e6e_0001.0000_e4f92437122f3e08\xmlFile.xml

while the xmlFile seems to be located in

> C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\8B40KE8T.5W0\VMZ0NKW3.PQR\bsb.exe_16b074f657bf9e6e_0001.0000_none_fd24e3b752f8dc74\xmlFile.xml

Notice the last directory being different. I understand that the executable is located in the first of these, but don't see how to then get to the resource file.
Additionally, I want to note that these paths seem weird to me to have something installed in, but this is no tragedy.